# Ansible expect module error

Tags: ansible, system-administration

I use Ansible 2.2.1.0

I try to use ansible expect module with a command:

```
expect:
    command: set password of database
    responses:
        Admin Password for db_name: 'admin'
        Admin Password Confirmation: 'admin'
```

I receive this error:

> fatal: [subdomain.xxxx.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Connection to sante.c3-bs.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ys2qrkdy/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 237, in \r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ys2qrkdy/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 149, in main\r\n    response = u'%s\n' % value.rstrip('\n').decode()\r\nAttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}

I don't understand this error can someone help me and give me the right 
responses or right syntaxe for expect command?

[edit]
**I give here all the commands:

```
- name: Configure tryton database
become: yes
become_method: sudo
become_user: root
expect:
    command: su - gnuhealth -c "python3 /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-4.2.6/bin/trytond-admin -c /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/config/trytond.conf -d db_name --all"
    responses:
        (?i)Admin Password for db_name: "admin"
        (?i)Admin Password Confirmation: "admin"
```

I use Python 2.7.9

Comment: Cannot be reproduced given the information in question.

Comment: Do you execute this module with Python2 or Python3?

Comment: I edit my post thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy fix seems to be using a newer ansible version. This or something similar seems to be fixed in version 2.4 - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/24269

You can use pip to install a newer version if your system does not provide one. Remember to uninstall system package first though.